# Is there a node.js method to read an index.html file and add new elements?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read my index.html file from my server.js in order to add a new

that links to a new html file I generate. I am using the POST method to do this and can successfully generate the new HTML file, however I am not sure how I can add a new

inside the index.HTML.

Here is my server.js:

```
    //POST method
  if(req.method === 'POST'){
    req.on('data', (data) => {
      let elementObj = querystring.parse(data.toString());
      element = elementObj.elementName;
      elementSymbol = elementObj.elementSymbol;
      elementAtomic = elementObj.elementAtomicNumber;
      elementDescription = elementObj.elementDescription;

      let newElement = fs.createWriteStream(`./public/${element}.html`);
      newElement.write(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>The Elements - ${element}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>${element}</h1>
<h2>${elementSymbol}</h2>
<h3>Atomic number ${elementAtomic}</h3>
<p>${elementDescription}</p>
<p><a href="/">back</a></p>
</body>
</html>`);

      let indexElements = document.querySelector('#elements');
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.setAttribute('href', `/${element}.html`);
      let elem = document.querySelector(`a[href = "/${element}.html"]`);
      elem.innerHTML = `${element}`;

      indexElements.appendChild(li);
      li.appendChild(a);

      res.end(data);
    });
  }
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Elements</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>The Elements</h1>
  <h2>These are all the known elements.</h2>
  <h3>These are 2</h3>
  <ol id = 'elements'>
    <li>
      <a href="/hydrogen.html">Hydrogen</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/helium.html">Helium</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
<script src="../../server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I want in my newly, modified index.html (new 'Boron' `<li>` added):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Elements</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>The Elements</h1>
  <h2>These are all the known elements.</h2>
  <h3>These are 2</h3>
  <ol id = 'elements'>
    <li>
      <a href="/hydrogen.html">Hydrogen</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/helium.html">Helium</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/boron.html">Boron</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
<script src="../../server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do because it appears you may be confused about what code runs on your server and what code runs in the browser.  But, (just guessing here) probably what you want is templates so you can create a shell for your HTML file and then use data to fill in pieces in the HTML shell and then send that to the client when requested.  I'd suggest a read here [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).  If you're not using Express for your web server, you probably should be.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks man, yes I understand that the DOM scripts don't belong on the server, but it is all I can think of what to do. Unfortunately, this is apart of an assignment and we're not allowed to use anything but node.js to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make it clear exactly what you're trying to do, but if these are your requirements:

1. You want to have an HTML template on disk.
2. That you can insert some content into based on some dynamic data.
3. You can't use anything other than plain node.js http server (so no existing template engines).

Then, you essentially have to build your own little template engine.  You can do that by reading the file into memory and then doing some sort of search/replace on some markers in the file to insert your content and then send that newly formed content.  Here's a general idea for how to do that:

Contents of template.html file on disk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Elements</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>The Elements</h1>
  <h2>These are all the known elements.</h2>
  <h3>These are 2</h3>
  <ol id='elements'>
    <li>
      <a href="/hydrogen.html">Hydrogen</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/helium.html">Helium</a>
    </li>
    <!-- new elements -->
  </ol>
<script src="../../server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server code for handling the POST

```
//POST method
if(req.method === 'POST'){
    req.on('data', (data) => {
        let elementObj = querystring.parse(data.toString());
        let element = elementObj.elementName;
        let elementSymbol = elementObj.elementSymbol;
        let elementAtomic = elementObj.elementAtomicNumber;
        let elementDescription = elementObj.elementDescription;

        fs.readFile("template.html", function(err, data) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).end();
            // build new content
            let newContent = "<li><a href=${element}.html>${element}</a></li>";
            data = data.replace(/<!-- new elements -->/, newContent);
            res.send(data);
        });
    });
});
```